# How can I pass an integer value as a parameter in my custom JSP tag?

Tags: jsp, el, strong-typing, custom-tags

I have a self made tag-library that I use in JSP. I have a problem with my `contains` -tag.

This is a generic contains-check, that accepts a list, and an object, and performs a simple check if the list contains the object. However, I've run into problems when the list contains Integer values.

This is how I call the tag:

```
<custom:contains  object="1" list="${sessionScope.USER.userProfiles}"/>
```

And here is the java class it invokes:

```
public class ContainsTag extends SimpleTagSupport{
    private List<Object> list;
    private Object object;

    public void setList(List<Object> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public void setObject(Object object) {
        this.object = object;
    }

    @Override
    public void doTag() throws JspException, IOException {      

        boolean result;
        try {
            if(list == null || object == null){
                result = false;
            }
            else{
                result = list.contains(object);
            }

            getJspContext().getOut().print(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            // stop page from loading further by throwing SkipPageException
            throw new SkipPageException("Exception in checking if " + list
                    + " contains " + object);
        }
    }
}
```

Printline statements show that even though the object prints `1`, and the list prints `[1]`, the result is `false`. Since the tag works for other types of objects (Strings etc), this leads me to the conclusion that object is a String value, and is therefor not found in a list of integers. I cannot exactly cast the object to an integer either, as my tag wouldn't be generic anymore.

Is there a way to specify that a parameter is an integer value in EL? Do I need to make another tag called `ContainsInteger`? Or are there other solutions to this problem?

**UPDATE:**

setting the object value to `"${1}"` instead of `"1"`, made no difference...

Comment: "...More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e)). " This will never be true in your case, because 1 is treated as String and (I guess) the members of your List are Integers. So either you should use some [Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html) or use a String-List.

Comment: Are you saying that there is no way of passing the value as a numeric integer? At the moment I am looking into if reflection can be used to typecast values, if they are not the same type. But it would just be so much more simple and clean, if i could specify that the value is supposed to be numeric.

Comment: That's why I suggested Generics. Do not use `Object` but T as type. I think it should be possible to treat the 1 as numeric 1 if the List is allowed to actually be a List of Integer rather than Object. If it is possible here. I have not so much experience with JSTL ...

Comment: Generic type doesn't matter. They're erased anyway. So your comment goes nowhere, Fildor. Hardcoded numbers in EL are just interpreted as `Long` which can never equal `Integer`. Nonetheless, why a whole tag instead of just `${someList.contains(object)}`, or aren't you on Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 yet? (while that's out for 6 years already)

Comment: Sounds very interesting. I am not very fluent in generics, but I'll give it a try. It seems cleaner than reflection anyway!

Comment: @BalusC thanks. So it could be a solution here to use a List of Long instead of Integer?

Comment: That would be one of the solutions, yes.

Comment: Many comments to answer at the time here :)

1. I am actually not sure of which versions I have. I normally do not use JSTL too much. I am still a novice/intermediate web developer, and most things can be done in javascript. In this case however, I'm working with user rights, which can't be exposed in the javascript.

Using Longs in my javabean-class is an option, although it seems overkill, as the number of different userprofiles, which the current int represents, probably will never exceed 10. Maybe not even 3.

Comment: I posted an answer. That said, whatever you have is not JSTL. To learn what exactly JSTL is, head to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: If I am correct, I am actually using servlet 2.3. I am using Eclipse, and changing project facets is hell on earth.

Comment: Huh, so JSTL is only the standard tag library. Nice to know the definition. So my custom tag library is not JSTL, just another tag library then? Or a jsp tag library?

Comment: btw, my work uses Weblogic 10.3.x servers, so I am not able to upgrade further than Servlet 2.5 anyway... EL 2.2 will not work for me, but nice to know that they have included a contains-tag there.

Comment: You've just a custom JSP tag library. As to EL 2.2, it's not that it added a bunch of functions, far from that, it's just that it allows invoking direct non-property methods on any object. The `contains()` method is here the actual method of the `List`, like as in plain Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `object="1"` won't work because it represents a `String`.

```
String string1 = "1";
Integer integer1 = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(string1.equals(integer1)); // false
```

The `object="${1}"` won't work because integer based numbers in EL default to `Long`. See section **"1.7.1 Binary operators - A {+,-,*} B"** in the ["Expression Language Specification"](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/el-3_0-fr-eval-spec/EL3.0.FR.pdf) (specified by [JSR-341](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=341)) for more details.

```
Long long1 = new Long(1L);
Integer integer1 = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(long1.equals(integer1)); // false
```

One way to solve your problem is to use a `List<Long>` instead of `List<Integer>`, or to let the custom tag compare the `toString()` result of both hands instead.

```
String string1 = "1";
Integer integer1 = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(string1.toString().equals(integer1.toString())); // true
```

```
Long long1 = new Long(1L);
Integer integer1 = new Integer(1);
System.out.println(long1.toString().equals(integer1.toString())); // true
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer. Even though it doesn't specifically say so, I read between the lines that specifying that a parameter is an integer value, is just not possible. 

Thanks for clarifying that EL defaults to long as well. The suggestion of using list of long instead of integer makes sense, but it just seems dirty to me. My integer values will probably never even be two digits long, and using a long for that, makes me feel all wrong inside. I'll look into upgrading to servlet 3.0/EL 2.2, use reflection to typecast, and/or make a new specific tag for containsInteger. But thanks a lot!

Comment: It would work if `1` were an integer based bean property like so `${someBean.userProfile}` instead of a hardcoded value. You didn't state the concrete functional requirements anywhere, but if I'd do an educated guess, I think you actually ultimately need enums.

Comment: hmmm. My user profiles are database-based. If I extract them, and pass them to a sessionScoped global app-data, I could just get the relevant integer values from there. That would be a great way. Enums might be a good idea too, but at my current level I am having a hard time wrapping my head around how to use enums in this case. I do think I will make this work very nice and clean now though! You are great. (Let me know if you ever need skydiving lessons. It is the perfect sport for deaf people)